# How to use CallFuncND in cocos2d for android

Tags: cocos2d-android

I want to call a method thrice with different parameters and need to have some delay between calling them,inorder to this i want to use `CCCallFuncND`,but i unable to implement it in my code, please help me do that by giving a simple example of how to call `CCCallFuncND`.

My Code is :

```
this.runAction(CCCallFuncND.action(this, "shift_sec", "1"));

public void shift_sec(String v) {
    System.out.println("Coming into this method. : "+v);          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will illustrate with example:

```
CCCallFuncND.action(this, "hitCallback", data)
```

here
   this--> is target  i.e sender

"hitCallback"------->  is the string which being called.

data ----------->  is an object to be send

```
public void hitCallback(Object sender,Object data){
        CCSprite hitSpotSprite = (CCSprite)data;
        hitSpotSprite.removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);
        hitSpotSprite = null;
    }
```

in your case 
`shift_sec(String v){}`  being modified to

```
shift_sec(Object sender,Object data){}
```